# twitter bootstrap thumbnail orientation switching with viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap and have 3 thumbnails at the bottom of a page, however as the viewport shrinks below 768px they change from being horizontally lined to vertically lined.  How can I stop this?

Here is the HTML I am using.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails noMargin offset5 bottomPage">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/45x45"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/45x45"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/45x45"></a>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is custom CSS I added

```
    <style>
.noMargin > li {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
body { 
    padding-top: 65px; 
}
.bottomPage{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5px;
}
    </style>
```

A js bin showing the issue. 
http://jsbin.com/opezov/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap-responsive.css line no 835 float:none; creating the problem

```
.thumbnails > li {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    }
```

Comment: I overrode this line and was able to fix the issue. Thanks for finding it!

Answer (score 0):

Removing

```
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

fix the issue if you don't need responsiveness on your page.

Otherwise refer to the Bootstap doc to prevent the responsive behaviour to happen (not sure if possible).